# cant set default options dropdown box

Tags: php, cakephp

I have populated a dropdown box with data and I can select from a list.I cant seem to set the option on to the selected value.I select a value and I want the drop down box to have the last selected value display   instead of resetting to the 1st option in the list. I have tried selected,default with and without numbers.

```
  public function admin_list($tutorId=0,$paycycleId=0) {

        if (isset($this->request->data['tutor'])) {
          debug($this->request->data['TimeSheet']['tutor']);
          $tutorId=$this->request->data['TimeSheet']['tutor'];
          return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin_list',$tutorId,$paycycleId));
      }//isset

  view////
     echo $this->Form->input('paycycle', array('label' => 'Pay Cycle Period',
                    'empty' =>array(0 => 'choose'), 'options' => $pcycle,'default'=>2 ));

          echo $this->Form->submit('Select a Pay Cycle', array('name'=>'paycycle'));
             echo $this->Form->end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the detailed instructions in the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs):

> Set ‘selected’ to the value of the item you wish to be selected by default when the input is rendered

Comment: ypu need to set the value. echo $this->Form->input('tutor', array('label' => 'Tutor',
                      'empty' =>array(0 => 'choose'),'options' => $tutor,'selected' => $tutorId  ));